# .setAttribute isn't hiding correctly. HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

```
 function displayEditProfileStudent() {
        document,getElementById('editstudentprofile').setAttribute('class', 'unhide');
        document.getElementById('profile_viewStudent').setAttribute('class', 'hide');
        document.getElementById('ViewStudent').setAttribute('class', 'unhide');
    }
    function displayProfileViewStudent() {
        document,getElementById('editstudentprofile').setAttribute('class', 'hide');
        document.getElementById('profile_viewStudent').setAttribute('class', 'unhide');
        document.getElementById('ViewStudent').setAttribute('class', 'unhide');
    }

<div id="ViewStudent" class="hide">
            <a href="#ViewProfileStudent" class="student_profile_view col-sm-1" onclick= "displayProfileViewStudent()" >View Profile</a>
            <a href="#EditProfileStudent" class="student_profile_edit col-sm-1" onclick="displayEditProfileStudent()">Edit Profile</a>
            <form id="editstudentprofile" class="hide">
                <h4>Edit Profile</h4>
                <label class="col-sm-3">Major:</label>
                <input class="major_input col-sm-5" name="studentmajor" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Major">
                <br/>
                <label class="col-sm-3">Cumulative GPA:</label>
                <input class="GPA_input col-sm-1" name="studentGPA" type="text" placeholder="GPA">
                <br/>
                <label class="col-sm-3">Expected Graduation Date:</label>
                <input class="graduation_input col-sm-2" name="studentgraduationdate" type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
                <br/>
                <label class="col-sm-3">Have you served as a TA before?</label><br/>
                <input class="previousTA_input" name="previousTA" type="radio"> Yes<br/>
                <input class="previousTA_input" name="previousTA" type="radio"> No<br/>
                <a href="#EditProfileStudent" class="editaccount_btn btn btn-default" >Update Profile</a>
            </form>
            <div id="profile_viewStudent" class="hide">
                <h4>Profile</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
```

when I click on the link for view profile/edit profile it wont show or hide the other, I am left looking the same screen. Any help is appreciated, I've tried scanning other posts and to my knowledge none have been helpful yet.

Also, here's the CSS of the hide class.

```
div.hide {
display: none;}

form.hide {
display: none;}
```

Comment: Paste your css also

Comment: you should be using classList to work with classes, not attributes. seems weird you would have hide and unhide classes/

Comment: I pasted the css, and I'll look into classList.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
document.getElementById('editstudentprofile').classList.add('unhide');
document.getElementById('editstudentprofile').classList.remove('hide');
```

Furthermore, in your example your using a `,` instead of a `.` after `document` in two lines.

Comment: yup, this was it! Thank you!